# Displayport 1.3 cable

Tags: monitors, display-port

I am looking for a new Display Port cable for my [Asus ROG SWIFT PG279Q](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/ROG-SWIFT-PG279Q/specifications/) monitor.  It has to work at 2560x1440 @ 165Hz and that is only possible with DisplayPort, however not all DP cables support this higher frequency.  Can anyone recommend a cable? I want to get my monitor working as best it can.

Comment: You're asking for a solution to a problem with a product that is still weeks or months away from being released to the market. A as I know there are currently no DisplayPort 1.3 graphics cards available. So even if someone labeled a cable as 1.3 *certified* you wouldn't be able to verify it currently and you can also not verify if the better 1.2 *certified* cables like AK-340100-030-S, which is already pretty thick, are sufficient.

Comment: With DP 1.2, they basically said *any* cerified DP cable should work I suspect the one in the box should be sufficient